# Overloading c# variable

Tags: c#

I'm a little new to C# and I've achieved something where I'm confused why this has been allowed.

```
public interface IBase
{
}

public interface ISub : IBase
{
}

public class Thing
{
    protected IBase provider;

    public Thing(IBase provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}

public class AnotherThing : Thing
{
    protected ISub provider;

    public AnotherThing(ISub provider) : base(provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

I hope I'm just being dense, but I don't understand how I am allowed to override `provider` without causing some confusion to the compiler.

The code does work.

Comment: Where / when should the compiler be confused?

Comment: I am changing the type of the variable `provider`

Comment: Look for a compiler warning about *hiding* that variable.

Comment: I had done a full rebuild but missed that warning, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised you are not getting any warning either.

What you are doing is [*hiding*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the protected member `provider` by providing a new declaration for it in the derived class. This is allowed, but you *should* decorate the declaration with the [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/435f1dw2.aspx) keyword to make it more explicit that you intended to hide the member and it was not just an accident/oversight.

Comment: I'd argue that instead of a warning it should really be an error - it's so easy to overlook the warning (as the OP has shown). If it was an error you would be forced to use `new`.

Comment: you hide a base class member when you provide a member in derived class *with the same type*. In this case the types are different. So it's not hiding, but redifinition of a new variable.

Comment: @Tigran, the documentation states: `A constant, field, property, or type introduced in a class or struct hides all base class members with the same name.` It doesn't say that the types have to be the same; just the name.

Comment: @James you can configure which compiler warnings you want to treat as errors.

Comment: It further says that: `A method introduced in a class or struct hides properties, fields, and types, with the same name, in the base class. It also hides all base class methods with the same signature.` So you could even use a method to hide a field..

Comment: @retailcoder yeah I know, my point was I don't think it should be optional I think it should be strict - that way the compiler won't just let you hide names unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about second case I presume:  you don't override anything, you just declare *a new* protected variable and explicitly reference it with `this`:

```
this.provider = provider;
```

As provider parameter is of type `ISub` the same type as the `this.provider`, compiler knows what variable you mean exactly.

Comment: aha so it's treating them as two seperate variables as if i had named one `foo` and the other `bar`?

Comment: It's treating them as 2 separate variables, yes, but it's not because they are 2 different types. The same code would work with the exact same type - it's matching them up via name.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a warning indicating that `provider` in `AnotherThing` is hiding an inherited member.

Effectively what happens is the compiler ignores `provider` in `Thing` when in the context of `AnotherThing` - it's known as [name hiding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).